# Remove characters from a word - VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to remove characters from a string based on the position. i use the below code and i manage to:

- Insert all word letters in an array
- Loop the array and replace the letters that i want with nothing

BUT i dont know have to remove nothing from the array, recreate array index and create the word again without those characters.

```
        'Create an array with all letters
        For j = 1 To Len(SheetName2)

            ReDim Preserve arrWord(k)
            arrWord(k) = Mid(SheetName2, j, 1)
            k = k + 1

        Next j

        Counter = (Len(SheetName2) - 31) * 2

        'Loop array and replace with nothing
        For w = Counter - 1 To 0 Step -2
            arrWord(w) = ""
        Next w
```

Comment: Can you show an Example ?

Comment: @Mikku there is no specific example, let say is a word and i want to delete characters based on there position

Comment: So you want to remove every 2nd letter in it ?

Comment: @Mikku exactly!Delete every second letter starting from a specific position.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an array of the characters. Just read every second character into a new string.

```
Public Sub OutputEverySecondChar()
    Dim TestString As String
    TestString = "abcdefghij"

    Dim OutputString As String

    Dim iChar As Long
    For iChar = 1 To Len(TestString) Step 2
        OutputString = OutputString & Mid$(TestString, iChar, 1)
    Next iChar

    Debug.Print OutputString 'output is: acegi
End Sub
```

---

Or even better as re-useable function:

```
Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print ReturnEveryXcharcter(InputString:="abcdefghij", FirstChar:=1, xChar:=2, CharLength:=1)
End Sub


Public Function ReturnEveryXcharcter(InputString As String, FirstChar As Long, xChar As Long, CharLength As Long) As String
    Dim iChar As Long
    For iChar = FirstChar To Len(InputString) Step xChar
        ReturnEveryXcharcter = ReturnEveryXcharcter & Mid$(InputString, iChar, CharLength)
    Next iChar
End Function
```

So the function is even more flexible and you can eg use the following to delete every 3ʳᵈ character (beginning with the first):

```
Debug.Print ReturnEveryXcharcter(InputString:="abcdefghij", FirstChar:=2, xChar:=3, CharLength:=2)
'output will be: bcefhi
```

---

Edit according comment:

Then loop until it is less then 31 characters:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"

    Do
        SheetName = ReturnEveryXcharcter(InputString:=SheetName, FirstChar:=1, xChar:=2, CharLength:=1, LengthLimit:=31)
    Loop While Len(SheetName) > 31

    Debug.Print SheetName
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The scenario has as follows, i have huge string and i want them to be the sheet name so i try to loop from the middle of the string removing every two characters until i meet the desired  length (31)

Comment: In case of >31 i want to loop to remove

Comment: @Error1004 Really? Please don't change your question everytime I answer. See my edit. If that is not what you want please give a full description of what you try to do (in your original question) **and an example** of input data and desired output (that you produce manually).

Comment: i have post my solution

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
If Len(SheetName1) > 31 Then

    SheetName2 = Replace(SheetName1, " ", "")

    'Third check - Remove letter by letter starting from the beginning
    If Len(SheetName2) > 31 Then

        Counter = (Len(SheetName2) - 31) * 2

        Part_1 = Left(SheetName2, Counter)
        Part_2 = Mid(SheetName2, Counter + 1, Len(SheetName2) - (Counter))

        Semi_Part = ""

        For j = 1 To Counter Step 2
            'Use only Part_1 because it ll be the same in all occurance
            Semi_Part = Semi_Part + Mid(Part_1, j, 1)

        Next j

        FinalSheetname = Semi_Part & Part_2

    Else
        FinalSheetname = SheetName2
    End If

Else

    FinalSheetname = SheetName1

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for interest, you can also do this with a worksheet function if you have one of the more recent versions of Excel (O365 or 2016+) that has the `CONCAT` function.

The "trick" is to create an array that includes the positions of the characters you wish to retain.

In the case of deleting every even space positioned character (retaining the odd positions):

```
=CONCAT(MID(A1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,ROUNDUP(LEN(A1)/2,0),1))-1)*2+1,1))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]